# Semantic UI and Styled-Components. Is this bad practice to use it rather then usual classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I always wrote the elements myself, but I found this service. I love this service, I like their style and speed, but looking to the future, I feel that it is unprofessional. Are such tools used in professional web development? And what do you say about Styled-components? Recently, I learned to write only on them, it's unusual, but I see that you can pass properties in them and use them again, but the application leaves a small mess of elements. will other developers understand me or is this also a bad practice.
Here an example of my code:

```
const CheckoutPage = ({ cartItems, total }) => (
  <CheckoutPageContainer>
    <CheckoutHeaderContainer>
      <HeaderBlockContainer>
        <span>Product</span>
      </HeaderBlockContainer>
      <HeaderBlockContainer>
        <span>Description</span>
      </HeaderBlockContainer>
      <HeaderBlockContainer>
        <span>Quantity</span>
      </HeaderBlockContainer>
      <HeaderBlockContainer>
        <span>Price</span>
      </HeaderBlockContainer>
      <HeaderBlockContainer>
        <span>Remove</span>
      </HeaderBlockContainer>
    </CheckoutHeaderContainer>
    {cartItems.map(cartItem => (
      <CheckoutItem key={cartItem.id} cartItem={cartItem} />
    ))}
    <TotalContainer>TOTAL: ${total}</TotalContainer>
    <WarningContainer>
      *Please use the following test credit card for payments*
      <br />
      4242 4242 4242 4242 - Exp: 01/20 - CVV: 123
    </WarningContainer>
    <StripeCheckoutButton price={total} />
  </CheckoutPageContainer>
);
```

But i found only one example like that, rest of code is fine.

Comment: What service? What tool(s)? It's completely unclear what you are really asking about. What specifically do you want understood from your snippet? I’m voting to close this question because it lacks focus and what is understood of questions seems likely to lead to opinionated answers.

Comment: @DrewReese Ops, my bad. I'll make some edits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Honestly, *Styled-Components* or the like, are very popular these days if not the norm so don't overthink it. I personally ALWAYS use *Styled-Components*. I feel It fits quite well with the React ecosystem.

Comment: thx bro! simple answer, love it!